# speeding up Gosper and WZ algorithms

Tags: computer-algebra, hypergeometric-functions, combinatorial-identities, symbolic-computation

In our ongoing work to speed up symbolic summation and other similar algorithms in [Sagemath](http://sagemath.org), we notice that naive implementations of [Gosper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm) and [Wilf-Zeilberger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) (a.k.a. WZ) algorithms are usually quite slow.

What is the state of the art here? E.g. is there software available that can derive Clausen $_4 F_3$ identity (see (V) on p.43 of the [A=B book](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)) quickly (few seconds on a laptop, say?) using the the WZ algorithm?

Comment: I am eager to try something called `fastZeil` they have at [RISC](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/risc/software/) but could not get response from them

Comment: fastZeil does seem to be available for download: http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/installation.html#download

Comment: No unfortunately it asks for username and password when you click there. I sent emails to a couple of addresses there but never got any answer

Comment: I just sent an email about this to someone at RISC I know...

Comment: Marko Petkovšek says that you should contact Peter Paule at Peter.Paule@risc.uni-linz.ac.at and ask for access to his implemetnations at http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ .

Comment: @AndrejBauer OMG the account from which I sent that request is so spam-contaminated I overlooked the response! I checked now, Peter Paule replied in mid December!! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The group at RISC has been working aggressively towards developing improved algorithms for many computer algebra problems, including the Zeilberger's. So, it is a good place to ask.

Meantime, I just wanted to say this regarding Clausen $_4 F_3$ identity that the OP mentioned. If you read on in the book A=B, on page 127 there is a rewrite of the identity and a procedure outlined as well. I just checked it myself using a much earlier version from Zeilberger, called [EKHAD](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/EKHAD), and executed in Maple. The verification of Clausen is instant!

Comment: p.127 gives $R(n,k)$. Do you mean to say that actually computing $R(n,k)$ is instant, or that carrying on if $R(n,k)$ is already known is instant?

Comment: I mean computing $R(n,k)$ is instant and hence proving the identity is instant, if you know how the WZ machinary works.